# Compose view moves following the wrong direction when panning after I rotated it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-gesture

Currently I have try the sample of [Multitouch: Panning, zooming, rotating](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/multi-touch) and I realized that the sample code might not work as expected. I rotated the compose view then drag it but it seems that the compose view is moving to the opposite direction of my dragging direction. Please help me find out what is the problem. Thanks!

[image]

This is my sample code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestComposeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    TransformableSample()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TransformableSample() {
    // set up all transformation states
    var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
        scale *= zoomChange
        rotation += rotationChange
        offset += offsetChange
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            // apply other transformations like rotation and zoom
            // on the pizza slice emoji
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = scale,
                scaleY = scale,
                rotationZ = rotation,
                translationX = offset.x,
                translationY = offset.y
            )
            // add transformable to listen to multitouch transformation events
            // after offset
            .transformable(state = state)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```